# jqgrid custom delete dialog message

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I want to customize the delete  dialog message. Based on a selected row?
I want to display a message something like "Delete selected row: $selectedRow.columnValue? "
How can i do that?

Comment: Did you use this jgrid : http://www.trirand.com/blog/ ?

Comment: What about your previous questions? Do you read the answers?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [beforeShowForm](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events2) or [afterShowForm](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events2) of the [delGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#delgridrow) to overwrite the text of the conformation dialog.

For example

```
beforeShowForm: function ($form) {
    $("td.delmsg", $form[0]).html("Do you really want delete the row with <b>id=" +
         $("#list").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow') + "</b>?");
}
```

(see [the old demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CustomDelMsg.htm)) will display the confirmation dialog like the following:

[image]

You can easy modify the example to display any other information about the deleting row. You can use [getRowData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) or [getCell](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) to get some information from the deleting row.

**UPDATED**: See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10050428/315935) for additional information.

Comment: +1 - yeah, I didn't think when I wrote my answer earlier.  Thanks.  You're definitely the jqgrid guru!

Comment: @Oleg: Hei, nice solution. But what if I want to get the message from server side? How do I specify the Url from which the message should be loaded? I am using .Net MVC 3.

Comment: @Mohaimin: It's full depend on how you use jqGrid in ASP.NET MVC 3. If you has `$("td.delmsg", $form[0]).html(...)` inside of aspx page for example the text `"Do you really want delete the row with <b>id="` can be generated by server code and be not a constant.

Comment: If id contains dot `.` or other special characters, hex code  appears instead. How to show real  id in delete prompt ?

Comment: @Oleg If there are multiple selected rows, how to select all row ids in prompt ? How to show id if it contains `.` or other special characters ? Currently hex code appears instead of dot

Comment: @Andrus: The current question has no relation to keyboard navigation. I posted you already [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/SetFocusInDeleteForm1.htm) which shows that if one set attributes `href: "#"`, `role: "button"` and `tabindex` on the buttons of Delete dialog then one can set focus by usage `$("#dData").focus()`.

Comment: @Oleg I modified comments and removed keyboard navigation parts. Questions about multiple ids print and id decoding are kept since those are related to this question.

Comment: @Andrus: I tried, but I could not reproduce any problem with ids having `.`. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/SetFocusInDeleteForm2.htm).

Answer (score 2):

if you start dialog with $('#dialog_id') then before you open your dialog change his html

```
$('#dialog_id').html('Delete selected row:' + $selectedRow.columnValue?);
$('#dialog_id').dialog();
```