# jqGrid how to center the Delete dialog when using formatter actions

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

I'm using jqGrid formatter action with a long grid, I'm trying to position the delete dialog in the center of the screen, I did that already but for some reason the window scrolls to the top of the grid and the dialog becomes invisible to the user

[Click here for a screencast of the issue](http://screenr.com/16d8)

Here's the code used:

```
    // define handler function for 'afterSubmit' event.
    var actionStatus = function(response,postdata){
    //alert($.parseJSON(response.responseText).USERDATA.MSG);
    aData = $.parseJSON(response.responseText).USERDATA;

    if (aData.STATUS){
        $.jgrid.info_dialog("Success", aData.MSG, $.jgrid.edit.bClose,{buttonalign:'right'});
        var thisId = aData.ID;
        $("#list").jqGrid('setGridParam',{loadComplete: function(){$(this).jqGrid('setRowData', thisId, false, 'mybold'); $("#" + thisId).effect("highlight", {color:"orange" }, 3000);}});
    }
    else {
        $(".topinfo").html(aData.MSG);
    }
    return [aData.STATUS, aData.MSG, aData.ID];
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    var grid = $("#list");
    var lastSel;
    var selICol; //iCol of selected cell
    var selIRow; //iRow of selected cell

    $("#list").jqGrid({
        url:'data.cfc?method=GetRecords', //CFC that will return the users
        datatype: 'json', //We specify that the datatype we will be using will be JSON
        //The JSON reader. This defines what the JSON data returned from the CFC should look like
        jsonReader: {
                      root: "DATA",
                      page: "CURPAGE",
                      total: "TOTALPAGES",
                      records: "TOTALROWS",
                      repeatitems: false,
                      id: ""
              },
        colNames: [ "YEAR", "SPC_CD", "SPC_CD", "BASE_COUNT", "BASE_MEDIAN", "START_COUNT", "START_MEDIAN", " "],
        /*
        If you want not display some columns which you need only to build the composite key you can use for this columns following options in the colModel
            hidden: true, editable: true, editrules: { edithidden: false }, hidedlg: true
        It will make columns invisible for user, but the data will be send to server at all edit operations.
        */
        colModel: [
            { name: "year", sortable: true, index:'year', editable: false, editoptions:{size:5, maxlength:4}, editrules:{required:true, integer:true}
            //, formoptions:{elmsuffix:" <img src='images/red_asterisk.gif' title='Required'>"} 
            },
            { name: "spc_cd", sortable: true, index:'spc_cd', editable: false, editoptions:{size:13, maxlength:10}, editrules:{required:true}
            //, formoptions:{ elmsuffix:" <img src='images/red_asterisk.gif' title='Required'>"} 
            },
            { name: "spc_cd", sortable: true, index:'spc_cd', editable: true, editoptions:{size:13, maxlength:10} },
            { name: "base_count", sortable: true, index:'base_count', editable: true, editoptions:{size:13, maxlength:10}, editrules:{integer:true} },
            { name: "base_median", sortable: true, index:'base_median', editable: true, editoptions:{size:13, maxlength:10}, editrules:{integer:true} },
            { name: "start_count", sortable: true, index:'start_count', editable: true, editoptions:{size:13, maxlength:10}, editrules:{integer:true} },
            { name: "start_median", sortable: true, index:'start_median', editable: true, editoptions:{size:13, maxlength:10}, editrules:{integer:true} 
                /*
                ,editOptions:{  dataEvents: [
                                    {
                                        type: 'keydown',
                                        fn: function (e) {
                                            var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode;
                                            if (key == 9)//tab
                                            {
                                                //Enter edit row for next row in grid
                                               // $('#list').jqGrid().editCell(" + selIRow + " + 1, " + selICol + ", true);
                                                $('#list').jqGrid("editCell", iRow+1, iCol, true)
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]                                               
                }
                */
            },
            { name: 'myac', width:60, fixed:true, sortable:false, resize:false, formatter:'actions', 
                formatoptions:{ keys:true
                                , editformbutton:false, 
                                editbutton : false, 
                                // For multi-column keys, we need to pass additional data to the delete function
                                delOptions:{ url:"data.cfc?method=delRecord", reloadAfterSubmit:true, closeOnEscape:true, afterSubmit: actionStatus, 
                                                serializeDelData: function (postdata) {
                                                    var rowdata = $('#list').getRowData(postdata.id);
                                                    // append postdata with any information 
                                                    //return {id: postdata.id, oper: postdata.oper, year: rowdata.year, spc_cd: rowdata.spc_cd};
                                                    postdata.year = rowdata.year;
                                                    postdata.spc_cd = rowdata.spc_cd;
                                                    return postdata;
                                                }, 
                                                recreateForm: true,
                                                beforeShowForm: function ($form) {
                                                    //var sel_id = $("#list").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                                                    //$("td.delmsg", $form[0]).html("Delete record with <b>id=" + $("#list").jqGrid('getCell', sel_id, 'spc_cd') + "</b>?");

                                                    var idOfDeletedRow = $("#DelData>td:first").text();
                                                    $("td.delmsg", $form[0]).html( "Delete record with <br><b>year=" +
                                                            $("#list").jqGrid('getCell', idOfDeletedRow, 'year') + "</b> and <b>spc_cd=" +
                                                            $("#list").jqGrid('getCell', idOfDeletedRow, 'spc_cd') + "</b> ?" );


                                                    //$("#delmod" + grid[0].id).addClass("centered");
                                                    var delDiv = $("#delmod" + grid[0].id);
                                                    delDiv.center();

                                                    //var scrollPosition = $("#list").closest(".ui-jqgrid-bdiv").scrollTop();
                                  // alert(scrollPosition);
                                   //selRowCoordinates = $('#'+selRowId).offset();
                              // delDiv.scrollTop(scrollPosition);

                                                    //var gviewHeight = $("#gview_" + $.jgrid.jqID(this.id)).outerHeight();
                                                    //delDiv.css({top:'50%',left:'50%',margin:'-'+(delDiv.height() / 2)+'px 0 0 -'+(delDiv.width() / 2)+'px'});
                                                }
                                                /*
                                                ,
                                                afterShowForm: function($form) {
                                    var $dialog = $form.closest('div.ui-jqdialog'),
                                        idOfDeletedRow = $("#DelData>td:first").text(),
                                        selRowCoordinates = $('#'+idOfDeletedRow).offset();

                                    $form.find("td.delmsg:first")
                                        .html("Delete record with <b>code=" +
                                            $("#list").jqGrid('getCell', idOfDeletedRow, 'cd') + "</b>?");
                                    $dialog.offset(selRowCoordinates);

                                        }
                                        */
                                }
                               /*
                               , 
                                editOptions:{ url:"data.cfc?method=editRecord", reloadAfterSubmit:true, closeOnEscape:true, closeAfterEdit:true, afterSubmit: actionStatus
                                                , serializeEditData: function (postdata) {
                                                    var rowdata = $('#list').getRowData(postdata.id);
                                                    // append postdata with any information 
                                                    postdata.old_year = rowdata.year;
                                                    postdata.old_spc_cd = rowdata.spc_cd;
                                                    return postdata;
                                                }                                               
                                }
                                */ 
                } 
            }
        ],
        afterEditCell: function(rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) {

            // Get a handle to the actual input field
            var inputControl = $('#' + (iRow) + '_' + cellname);

            // Listen for tab on col #7 START_MEDIAN, which is the last editable column in the row
            // as we need to move to the first editable cell in the next row
            if ( iCol == 7 ){
                inputControl.bind("keydown",function(e) {               
                    if (e.charCode || e.keyCode === 9) {  // Enter key:

                        var increment = 1;
                        // Do not go out of bounds
                        var lastRowInd = $("#list").jqGrid("getGridParam","reccount");
                        if ( iRow+increment == 0 || iRow+increment == lastRowInd+1)
                            return;   // we could re-edit current cell or wrap
                        else
                            $("#list").jqGrid("editCell", iRow+increment, 3, true); //move to the first editable cell (#3) in the next row
                    }
                });
            } // End keydown binding
        },
        beforeEditCell : function(rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol){
            selICol = iCol;
            selIRow = iRow;
        },
        /*
        onSelectRow: function(id) {
                    if (id && id !== lastSel) {
                        $("#list").jqGrid('restoreRow',lastSel);
                        lastSel = id;
                    }
                },
                ondblClickRow: function(id, ri, ci) {
                    $("#list").jqGrid('editRow',id,true);
                    return;
                },
        */
        cellEdit : true,
        cellsubmit : 'clientArray',
        onPaging : isDataChanged,
        hidegrid: false,
        shrinkToFit: true,
        altRows: true,
        toppager: true,
        gridview: true, //speed the reading process for large data sets
        ignoreCase: true, //when sorting
        pager: $('#pager'), //The div we have specified, tells jqGrid where to put the pager
        rowNum:100, //Number of records we want to show per page
        //rowList:[20,50], //Row List, to allow user to select how many rows they want to see per page
        rowTotal: 1000, // get this number of rows from the server
        //loadonce:true, //load all the needed data from server at once and then operate on it locally
        sortorder: "desc", //Default sort order
        sortname: "year,spc_cd", //Default sort column
        //viewsortcols: true, // view sortable columns
        viewrecords: true, //Shows the nice message on the pager
        //imgpath: '/Test/themes/basic/images', //Image path for prev/next etc images
        caption: 'Table: DATA_TEST', //Grid Name
        recordtext: "Record {0} - {1} of {2}",//Pager information to show
        rownumbers: true,//Show row numbers
        rownumWidth: "40",//Width of the row numbers column
        sortable: true,
        width: 'auto',
        height:'auto', //I like auto, so there is no blank space between. Using a fixed height can mean either a scrollbar or a blank space before the pager
        mtype:'POST',   
        //toolbar:[true,"top"], //Shows the toolbar at the top. We will use it to display user feedback
        //editurl:"data.cfc?method=editRecord" //The Add/Edit function call
        //editurl: 'clientArray',
        }

    );

    $("#list").jqGrid(
        'navGrid',
        '#list_toppager', //The id of the top pager is a combination of grid id and “_toppager”
        {addicon:"ui-icon-circle-plus", addtext:"Add New Record&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;", addtitle:"", del:false, edit:false, search:false, closeOnEscape:true}, //options 
        {}, //edit options
        {url:"data.cfc?method=addRecord", reloadAfterSubmit:true, closeAfterAdd: true, afterSubmit: actionStatus, 
            // make the primary key columns editable in add mode
            beforeInitData: function(formid) {
                $("#list").jqGrid('setColProp','year',{editable:true});
                $("#list").jqGrid('setColProp','spc_cd',{editable:true});
            },
            // after the form is shown, revert the primary key columns to un-editable
            afterShowForm: function (formid) {
                $("#list").jqGrid('setColProp','year',{editable:false});
                $("#list").jqGrid('setColProp','spc_cd',{editable:false});
            }
        }, // add options 
        {}, // del options
        {}, // search options
        {closeOnEscape:true}
    ); //.navSeparatorAdd('#list_toppager');

    $("#list").jqGrid().navGrid().navButtonAdd('#list_toppager',
            {
                caption: "Save Changed Rows&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;",
                buttonicon: "ui-icon-disk",
                onClickButton: function () {
                    $("#list").jqGrid("restoreCell", selIRow, selICol, true); //if there's an open cell, first restore it
                    var ret = $("#list").getChangedCells('all');
                    //console.dir(ret);
                    //console.info($('#1_base_count').val());
                    var ret2 = JSON.stringify(ret);
                    //console.info(ret2);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "post",
                        url: "data.cfc?method=editRecord",
                        data: { jsonData: ret2 },
                        // contentType: "application/json",
                        //dataType: "json",
                        success: function(data) {
                            $.jgrid.info_dialog("Success", "Rows Updated Successfully", $.jgrid.edit.bClose,{buttonalign:'right'});
                            /*
                            $('<div></div>').html(data).dialog({
                                'title' : 'Message',
                                'modal' : true,
                                'width' : 400,
                                'height' : 400,
                                'buttons' : {
                                    'OK' : function() {
                                        $(this).dialog('close');
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                            */
                            $('#list').trigger('reloadGrid');
                        },
                        error: function(){
                            $.jgrid.info_dialog("Error", "Error Occurred while saving data", $.jgrid.edit.bClose,{buttonalign:'right'});
                        }
                    });
                },
                position: "first"
            }
            ); //.navSeparatorAdd('#list_toppager');



//Supresss jqGrid error dialog, called #info_dialog
            /*
            $("#delmodlist").live("focus", function () {

                var errorMessage = $("#delmsg").text();
                $("#delmodlist").center();
                $("#delmodlist").blur();


            });
            */
    //$("#list").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{stringResult: true,searchOnEnter : false});

    //$("#list_toppager_center").hide();    

});
// define handler function for 'afterSubmit' event.
var actionStatus = function(response,postdata){
aData = $.parseJSON(response.responseText).USERDATA;

    if (aData.STATUS){
        $.jgrid.info_dialog("Success", aData.MSG, $.jgrid.edit.bClose,{buttonalign:'right'});
    else {
        $(".topinfo").html(aData.MSG);
    }
    return [aData.STATUS, aData.MSG, aData.ID];
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    var grid = $("#list");
    var lastSel;
    var selICol; //iCol of selected cell
    var selIRow; //iRow of selected cell

    $("#list").jqGrid({
        url:'data.cfc?method=GetRecords', //CFC that will return the users
        datatype: 'json', //We specify that the datatype we will be using will be JSON
        //The JSON reader. This defines what the JSON data returned from the CFC should look like
        jsonReader: {
                      root: "DATA",
                      page: "CURPAGE",
                      total: "TOTALPAGES",
                      records: "TOTALROWS",
                      repeatitems: false,
                      id: ""
              },
        colNames: [ "YEAR", "CD", "SPC_CD", "BASE_COUNT", "BASE_MEDIAN", "START_COUNT", "START_MEDIAN", " "],
        /*
        If you want not display some columns which you need only to build the composite key you can use for this columns following options in the colModel
            hidden: true, editable: true, editrules: { edithidden: false }, hidedlg: true
        It will make columns invisible for user, but the data will be send to server at all edit operations.
        */
        colModel: [
            { name: "year", sortable: true, index:'year', editable: false, editoptions:{size:5, maxlength:4}, editrules:{required:true, integer:true}
            //, formoptions:{elmsuffix:" <img src='images/red_asterisk.gif' title='Required'>"} 
            },
            { name: "cd", sortable: true, index:'cd', editable: false, editoptions:{size:13, maxlength:10}, editrules:{required:true}
            //, formoptions:{ elmsuffix:" <img src='images/red_asterisk.gif' title='Required'>"} 
            },
            { name: "spc_cd", sortable: true, index:'spc_cd', editable: true, editoptions:{size:13, maxlength:10} },
            { name: "base_count", sortable: true, index:'base_count', editable: true, editoptions:{size:13, maxlength:10}, editrules:{integer:true} },
            { name: "base_median", sortable: true, index:'base_median', editable: true, editoptions:{size:13, maxlength:10}, editrules:{integer:true} },
            { name: "start_count", sortable: true, index:'start_count', editable: true, editoptions:{size:13, maxlength:10}, editrules:{integer:true} },
            { name: "start_median", sortable: true, index:'start_median', editable: true, editoptions:{size:13, maxlength:10}, editrules:{integer:true} 
                /*
                ,editOptions:{  dataEvents: [
                                    {
                                        type: 'keydown',
                                        fn: function (e) {
                                            var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode;
                                            if (key == 9)//tab
                                            {
                                                //Enter edit row for next row in grid
                                               // $('#list').jqGrid().editCell(" + selIRow + " + 1, " + selICol + ", true);
                                                $('#list').jqGrid("editCell", iRow+1, iCol, true)
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]                                               
                }
                */
            },
            { name: 'myac', width:60, fixed:true, sortable:false, resize:false, formatter:'actions', 
                formatoptions:{ keys:true
                                , editformbutton:false, 
                                editbutton : false, 
                                // For multi-column keys, we need to pass additional data to the delete function
                                delOptions:{ url:"data.cfc?method=delRecord", reloadAfterSubmit:true, closeOnEscape:true, afterSubmit: actionStatus, 
                                                serializeDelData: function (postdata) {
                                                    var rowdata = $('#list').getRowData(postdata.id);
                                                    // append postdata with any information 
                                                    //return {id: postdata.id, oper: postdata.oper, year: rowdata.year, cd: rowdata.cd};
                                                    postdata.year = rowdata.year;
                                                    postdata.cd = rowdata.cd;
                                                    return postdata;
                                                }, 
                                                recreateForm: true,
                                                beforeShowForm: function ($form) {
                                                                        var idOfDeletedRow = $("#DelData>td:first").text();
                                                    $("td.delmsg", $form[0]).html( "Delete record with <br><b>year=" +
                                                            $("#list").jqGrid('getCell', idOfDeletedRow, 'year') + "</b> and <b>spc_cd=" +
                                                            $("#list").jqGrid('getCell', idOfDeletedRow, 'spc_cd') + "</b> ?" );


                                                    var delDiv = $("#delmod" + grid[0].id);
                                                    //delDiv.center();

                                                        }
                                                /*
                                                ,
                                                afterShowForm: function($form) {
                                    var $dialog = $form.closest('div.ui-jqdialog'),
                                        idOfDeletedRow = $("#DelData>td:first").text(),
                                        selRowCoordinates = $('#'+idOfDeletedRow).offset();

                                    $form.find("td.delmsg:first")
                                        .html("Delete record with <b>code=" +
                                            $("#list").jqGrid('getCell', idOfDeletedRow, 'cd') + "</b>?");
                                    $dialog.offset(selRowCoordinates);

                                        }
                                        */
                                }

                } 
            }
        ],
        afterEditCell: function(rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) {

            // Get a handle to the actual input field
            var inputControl = $('#' + (iRow) + '_' + cellname);

            // Listen for tab on col #7 START_MEDIAN, which is the last editable column in the row
            // as we need to move to the first editable cell in the next row
            if ( iCol == 7 ){
                inputControl.bind("keydown",function(e) {               
                    if (e.charCode || e.keyCode === 9) {  // Enter key:

                        var increment = 1;
                        // Do not go out of bounds
                        var lastRowInd = $("#list").jqGrid("getGridParam","reccount");
                        if ( iRow+increment == 0 || iRow+increment == lastRowInd+1)
                            return;   // we could re-edit current cell or wrap
                        else
                            $("#list").jqGrid("editCell", iRow+increment, 3, true); //move to the first editable cell (#3) in the next row
                    }
                });
            } // End keydown binding
        },
        beforeEditCell : function(rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol){
            selICol = iCol;
            selIRow = iRow;
        },

        cellEdit : true,
        cellsubmit : 'clientArray',
        onPaging : isDataChanged,
        hidegrid: false,
        shrinkToFit: true,
        altRows: true,
        toppager: true,
        gridview: true, //speed the reading process for large data sets
        ignoreCase: true, //when sorting
        pager: $('#pager'), //The div we have specified, tells jqGrid where to put the pager
        rowNum:100, //Number of records we want to show per page
        rowTotal: 1000, // get this number of rows from the server
        sortorder: "desc", //Default sort order
        sortname: "year,spc_cd", //Default sort column
        viewrecords: true, //Shows the nice message on the pager

        caption: 'Table: DATA_TEST', //Grid Name
        recordtext: "Record {0} - {1} of {2}",//Pager information to show
        rownumbers: true,//Show row numbers
        rownumWidth: "40",//Width of the row numbers column
        sortable: true,
        width: 'auto',
        height:'auto', //I like auto, so there is no blank space between. Using a fixed height can mean either a scrollbar or a blank space before the pager
        mtype:'POST'
        }

    );

    $("#list").jqGrid(
        'navGrid',
        '#list_toppager', //The id of the top pager is a combination of grid id and “_toppager”
        {addicon:"ui-icon-circle-plus", addtext:"Add New Record&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;", addtitle:"", del:false, edit:false, search:false, closeOnEscape:true}, //options 
        {}, //edit options
        {url:"data.cfc?method=addRecord", reloadAfterSubmit:true, closeAfterAdd: true, afterSubmit: actionStatus, 
            // make the primary key columns editable in add mode
            beforeInitData: function(formid) {
                $("#list").jqGrid('setColProp','year',{editable:true});
                $("#list").jqGrid('setColProp','cd',{editable:true});
            },
            // after the form is shown, revert the primary key columns to un-editable
            afterShowForm: function (formid) {
                $("#list").jqGrid('setColProp','year',{editable:false});
                $("#list").jqGrid('setColProp','cd',{editable:false});
            }
        }, // add options 
        {}, // del options
        {}, // search options
        {closeOnEscape:true}
    ); //.navSeparatorAdd('#list_toppager');

    $("#list").jqGrid().navGrid().navButtonAdd('#list_toppager',
            {
                caption: "Save Changed Rows&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;",
                buttonicon: "ui-icon-disk",
                onClickButton: function () {
                    $("#list").jqGrid("restoreCell", selIRow, selICol, true); //if there's an open cell, first restore it
                    var ret = $("#list").getChangedCells('all');
                    //console.dir(ret);
                    //console.info($('#1_base_count').val());
                    var ret2 = JSON.stringify(ret);
                    //console.info(ret2);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "post",
                        url: "data.cfc?method=editRecord",
                        data: { jsonData: ret2 },
                        // contentType: "application/json",
                        //dataType: "json",
                        success: function(data) {
                            $.jgrid.info_dialog("Success", "Rows Updated Successfully", $.jgrid.edit.bClose,{buttonalign:'right'});

                            $('#list').trigger('reloadGrid');
                        },
                        error: function(){
                            $.jgrid.info_dialog("Error", "Error Occurred while saving data", $.jgrid.edit.bClose,{buttonalign:'right'});
                        }
                    });
                },
                position: "first"
            }
            ); 



});
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to post a jsfiddle or other code example demonstrating the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You don't posted the code of `center` method which you use or describe which plugin you use. In any way I think that you should use `delDiv.center();` inside of `afterShowForm` and not inside of `beforeShowForm`.

Like you can see on [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ChangeDelDialogPosition1.htm) the problem with scrolling should not exist in general.

Comment: Here's the center method `jQuery.fn.center = function (parent) {
 if (parent) {
  parent = this.parent();
 } else {
  parent = window;
 }

 this.css({
  "position": "absolute",
  "top": ((($(parent).height() - this.outerHeight()) / 2) + $(parent).scrollTop() + "px"),
  "left": ((($(parent).width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2) + $(parent).scrollLeft() + "px")
 });
 return this;
}`

Comment: @AE: I can't test your code. Do you tried my demo? Is it do what you need? Do you tried to center dialog inside of `afterShowForm` instead of `beforeShowForm`?

Comment: Dear Oleg, actually if you click on any part of the actions cell it takes you to the top of the grid, so the afterShowForm or beforeShowForm is not triggered yet at that point

Comment: @AE: I asked you some questions. Could you answer on there? Is the demo which I posted what you need?

Comment: It still hasn't worked, I need to try it out from scratch. Thanks Oleg

Comment: @AE: I can't help you if you ignore my questions about the problem which you have. What is not worked? Is [my demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ChangeDelDialogPosition1.htm) doesn't work in some scenario? How exactly I can reproduce the problem? Is your demo doesn't work? Please answer on my previous questions if you want to continue dialog with me.