# jqGrid: how to keep the 'Save' button enabled after adding a row

Tags: jqgrid

Im looking for a way to add a new row and keep the form data together with the Save button enabled, to have the chance to resend the same data already sent.

What im trying to achieve is to facilitate the submission of similar-but-not-equal rows. So, for example, if a merchant receives an order all of the same X product, but with slightly differences, he can keep the common fields after saving a product and only change the different properties to submit the next one, and so on.

Then the server will throw an error if exactly the same data is sent more than once.

Comment: Form adding or inline adding?

Comment: Would it make more sense to change the form with an extra "Save with New" (or something like that) button, where on that trigger you would copy out the values, save, then launch a new add window and copy the values into the fields.  Maybe that is more complicated but was the first thing I thought of as an approach to your problem.

Comment: Thanks Mark, im trying to get an easier solution before getting into that. You know, the only problems is the 'Save' button changing its onClick behavior, i could give a try to modify that in the jqgrid js file, but i would like to be free to perform library upgrades too.

Comment: Actually in my thought process you would give the user two save buttons, one which is the default, and the second would be the "Save with New" acting as a kind of template option for your new record.

Comment: What about adding a button that just re sends the form contents to the server, and doesn't get disabled after doing so? Can you post the process of adding the new button and getting the forms data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jqGrid 4.4.4, file jquery.jqGrid.min.js:

At line 279, after 'beforeSubmit' takes place, you will find the following statement: if(k[0]&&!b[d.p.id].processing), the second part of the test means something like 'if request is not being processed', then after the 'processing' variable is set to true, the request to the server is performed.

What prevents to resend data is that the processing variable is never set back to false 'afterSubmit' for example.

So, my solution was to do exactly that: b[d.p.id].processing=false; at the end of the if block performing the action, this is done on line 287, col 55.

This way i can resend slightly different 'products' and just let the server to manage errors.

I suppose it could be a bug in the library to not 'close' the processing state by setting back the variable to false.

Answer (score 0):

As per our discussion I would refer to the following as an example of adding a custom button to the Add form:

[How to add custom buttons to JqGrid add/edit forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10320523/how-to-add-custom-buttons-to-jqgrid-add-edit-forms)

as for saving the information you can use the the documentation as an example, I think the `beforeSubmit` event would work for saving the field data