# Jqgrid custom delete message

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am using jqgrid and I like to display custom message while deleting a row. Something like If i delete a row where column1 contains "value1" then my message should be "Do you want to delete this configuration?", or if the deleting row's column1 has "value2" then the message should be "Deleting this will affect the usual flow. Do you really want to delete ? " Some thing like this. Is it possible to achieve this using jqgrid ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to change the text of the Delete message inside of `beforeShowForm` like it in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10050428/315935).