# jqgrid with custom delete dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

I am using Jqgrid for displaying information. Is it possible to have custom delete dialog on deleting any row. Since I want to display one more button along with "delete" and "cancel" and also need to display checkbox. Is it possible to customize or create new dialog and display it at the time of deleting a row ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [jqgrid custom delete dialog message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913618/jqgrid-custom-delete-dialog-message).

The answer in this question touches on customizing the dialog text, and not necessarily the form elements. You would just have to alter the html code (still utilizing the event callbacks) to add the checkbox to the other section of the form, ie

```
beforeShowForm: function ($form) {
    $(".DeleteButton.EditButton", $form[0]).prepend('<label><checkbox name="cb">Text label</label>');
}
```

you may have to adjust the selector